# how to avoid 1900-01-01 in SQL 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am joining two table to make aggregate records in final table.

However, the issue is when I am joining two tables based on matched column, I am getting `1900-01-01` date instead of required original date.

I am using full join in SQL server 2008 R2.

What is the main reason behind this as, because of this `1900-01-01` date all records are fluctuating with `5%-10%`.

So, how can i solve this issue in database?

Comment: Just don't put in that value?

Comment: Can you add table definitions for the two tables you are joining with maybe a row of sample data in each?

Comment: Well, can we see the code you are using?, how are we supposed to know what is the main reason behind this otherwise?

Comment: hi all, the code is below that i am using rite now for join statement;

Comment: Hi ALL,I have just add code in different questions for same issue. you all all can refer that.

Comment: Where is that different question?  Please provide a link.

Comment: @Ann L.; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488799/how-to-avoid-default-date-1900-01-01-in-sql-server-2008-r2-during-join-statement