# How to avoid default date 1900-01-01 in SQL Server 2008 R2 during join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT IsNull(cmg.[Advertiser],
    con.[Advertiser]) as [Advertiser] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[AdvertiserID],
    con.[AdvertiserID]) as [AdvertiserID] ,
    con.[FloodlightConfiguration] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[Campaign],
    con.[Campaign]) as [Campaign] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[CampaignID],
    con.[CampaignID]) as [CampaignID] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[Placement],
    con.[Placement]) as [Placement] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[PlacementID],con.[PlacementID]) as [PlacementID] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[Creative],con.[Creative]) as [Creative] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[CreativeID],con.[CreativeID]) as [CreativeID] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[AD],con.[AD]) as [AD] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[ADID],
    con.[ADID]) as [ADID] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[Country],
    con.[Country]) as [Country] ,
    con.[Activity] ,
    con.[ActivityID] ,
    IsNull(cmg.[DeliveryDate],0) as [ConversionDate] ,
    IsNull(con.[TotalConversions],0) as [TotalConversions] ,
    IsNull(con.[TotalRevenue],0) as [TotalRevenue] ,
    IsNull([ClickthroughConversions],0) as [ClickthroughConversions] ,
    IsNull([ClickthroughRevenue],0) as [ClickthroughRevenue] ,
    IsNull([ViewthroughConversions],0) as [ViewthroughConversions] ,
    IsNull([ViewthroughRevenue],0) as [ViewthroughRevenue] ,
    case when con.[ActivityID] is not null then 0 else cmg.Impressions end as Impressions,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT Null then 0 else cmg.Clicks end AS Clicks,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.MediaCost end as MediaCost,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.ActivityPerClick end as ActivityPerClick,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.ActivityPerThousandImpressions end as ActivityPerThousandImpressions,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.CostPerActivity end as CostPerActivity,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.CostPerClick end as CostPerClick,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.CostPerRevenue end as CostPerRevenue,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.EffectiveCPM end as EffectiveCPM ,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.RevenuePerClick end as RevenuePerClick,
    case when con.[ActivityID] IS NOT NULL then 0 else cmg.RevenuePerThousandImpressions end as RevenuePerThousandImpressions 
FROM [DM_886_MarriottSocialData].[dbo].[DFA_BSE_DIS_MD_1] cmg
    FULL OUTER JOIN [DM_886_MarriottSocialData].[dbo].[DFA_BSE_DIS_CON_1] con
        ON cmg.PlacementID = con.PlacementID 
            AND cmg.DeliveryDate = con.ConversionDate 
            AND cmg.CampaignID = con.CampaignID 
            AND cmg.Country = con.Country 
            AND cmg.ADID = con.ADID 
            AND cmg.CreativeID = con.CreativeID 
            AND cmg.AdvertiserID = con.AdvertiserID 
WHERE cmg.DeliveryDate >= '2014-01-01' 
    AND cmg.DeliveryDate <= '2014-03-16'
```

This is the code I am using currently to evaluate aggregate table but i am getting 1900-01-01 default date in some records. however, i want those all records in final table. The reason is because of 1900-01-01 some columns are effecting with 5%-10% of fluctuation in their respective values.

Thanks

Comment: Why the full outer join?

Comment: @Charleh: Because we want all records from both table.

Comment: Which column is the one that's getting the `19000101` date?. Also, by using you current filter (`cmg.DeliveryDate >= '2014-01-01' AND cmg.DeliveryDate <= '2014-03-16'`) you are effectively converting your `FULL JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Lamak: The clicks, impressions  column is getting effected, And (cmg.DeliveryDate >= '2014-01-01' AND cmg.DeliveryDate <= '2014-03-16') is just where condition I have put and you don't need to worry about. I am talking about data from 2013-01-01 to 2014-03-16.

Comment: I'm asking which date column is being converted to '19000101'. For instance, this part of your code: `IsNull(cmg.[DeliveryDate],0)` is effectively converting a date to '19000101' in the case of being `NULL`. If you want another value for the null dates, then choose something other than `0`, it's that simple

Comment: @user3299024 Well, as I said, you are using `ISNULL(cmg.[DeliveryDate],0)`, so when that column is `NULL` you are **assigning** the value 0 (which gets translated to `19000101`). It's a `DATETIME`, so first of all you need to know which date you want to assign in this cases and then assign **that** date instead of `0` (which is getting casted to 19000101)

Comment: @Lamak: I got your point so can i do one thing to remove isnull and just put simple cmg.deliverydate as deliverydate? becuase this is not about particular date ,each date have affected.

Comment: I don't know because I don't understand what you are doing. Just explaining **why** you are getting the results you are getting.

Comment: ok thanks Lamak for your help, i will try with different idea. will ask questions if i will get something. Thanks again!